# How to add a function to each ID, selecting by class?

Tags: jquery, html, class, each

I tried this, but it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me please? Thank you!

JS :

```
function thumbnail(param1){
    $(param1).hover(
        function() {
            $(param1+' .color').hide().stop().fadeTo(500,'1');
        },
        function() {
            $(param1+' .color').stop().fadeTo(500,'0');
        }
    );                 
};

$("div.thumb").each(function (){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');  
    thumbnail(id);
});
```

Comment: "This doesn't work" is about as much information as asking a potato for directions to Namibia's North Coast resorts. Please give any errors printed by the error console, or any incorrect behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID selector in jquery is `#someId`.

You should do this:

```
$('#' + param1)
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `$(param1)`, use `$('#'+param1)` for an element ID, or `$('.'+param1)` for a class.

Answer (score 0):

I would just send the jquery object, myself.

```
function thumbnail($param1){
$param1.hover(
    function() {
        $param1.find(".color").hide().stop().fadeTo(500,'1');
    },
    function() {
        $param1.find(".color").stop().fadeTo(500,'0');
    }
) ;                 
};


$("div.thumb").each(function (){
    thumbnail($(this))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete code:

```
function thumbnail(param1){
    $('#' + param1).hover(
        function() {
            $('#' + param1 + ' .color').hide().stop().fadeTo(500,'1');
        },
        function() {
            $('#' + param1 + ' .color').stop().fadeTo(500,'0');
        }
    ) ;                 
    };

    $("div.thumb").each(function (){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');  
        thumbnail(id);});
```